# Can not update text in .gsp file

Tags: grails

I am new to grails framework. I have grails web application already deployed on weblogic server.

I updated small text in index.gsp file that resides under \myapplicationWEB-INF\grails-app\views\resetPassword

I repacked the war file using jar -cvf command with above change and redeployed the war to weblogic server. But updated content is not appearing when i render this index file through UI. What am I missing?

I am not sure if i have to regenerate war file using grails command. I deployed the updated war file on different weblogic instance as well. But i dont see the changes being reflected.

```
<div class="fb-input-box">
                    <g:field type="text" name="UID" maxlength="6" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{4,4}" data-validation-error-msg="Your UID is invalid." required="required"  /> 
                    <div class="fb-hint">
                    UID is your 6-digit Company ID </div>
            </div>
```

Expected Result is **UID is your 6-digit Company ID**.
Actual Result is **UID is your 6-digit Company Associate Number**

Comment: Can you verify that your updated war file contains the changes you made? You can open a war file with just a zip extract utility and check the text files.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build a new WAR file using the [grails war](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html) command and redeploy it to Weblogic.

Comment: i downloaded grails 3.3.9 on windows. But grails war command is not recognized in this version. The WAR file was built using grails 2.0.4. Do you know how to download gails 2.0.4?

Comment: @user2961454 you can download any version of Grails here https://grails.org/download.html

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I wouldn't be edited the deployed jar, unless it was an absolute emergency, as I would consider that bad practice. Instead I would go back to the source code, edited the gsp file, test it, commit it to source control, build a new jar, and deploy the new jar. You can automate some of that process with a CI machine, and you should probably have QA involved in testing, before deploying to production.

Comment: He's deploying to Weblogic, so I guess he needs to build a WAR, rather than a self-executing JAR.